# jsdoc type union, comparison overlap

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, jsdoc, union-types

The code:

```
// @ts-check
/** @type {('standalone' | 'export' | undefined)} */
const output = 'standalone';

output === 'export'; // <-- this generates an `typescript 2367` error
```

> Typescript 2367 Errror:
> This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '"standalone"' and '"export"' have no overlap

Using JSDoc, how can I could solve this kind of problem?

I just tried typedef the value first, I tried to follow some cheatsheets, but, I have no idea anymore.

some sources:

- https://docs.joshuatz.com/cheatsheets/js/jsdoc/
- https://devhints.io/jsdoc
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#type

Comment: if its a `const`, it can't change. so its moot to compare

Comment: Yeah! I have no intention to change this variable along the code, but it's a variable from a config that I have to check a lot of things based at the same variable, and that would be very redundant

Comment: Ohhh, I see what you saying, so I just used
`// eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const`, thanks!